# How do I conditionally add items to the statusline?

Tags: statusline

As a simple example, let's say I want to show the line number only when `:spell` is set. I would assume the following would work, but does not.

`%{&spell ? %l : ""}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 ways to change the value of an option, with the `:set` or `:let` command.

```
:set myoption=myvalue
:setlocal mylocaloption=mylocalvalue
```

Or:

```
:let &myoption = 'myvalue'
:let &l:mylocaloption = 'mylocalvalue'
```

---

When you use the `:set` command, the value you assign to the option can contain characters which have a special meaning on the command-line. To avoid errors, you should tell Vim they are regular characters, by escaping them. Among these special characters, there are `"` (beginning of a comment), and `Space` (separation between 2 option names).

To get back to your issue, you want to display the current line number. I don't think you can use the item `%l` inside the curly braces, because inside them Vim expects an expression, and `%l` is not an expression.
However, it can be retrieved with the `line()` function: `line('.')`.

So, to show the current line number in the status line, only when `'spell'` is enabled, you could write:

```
set stl+=%{&spell\ ?\ line(\".\")\ :\ \"\"}
```

But the backslashes make the expression difficult to read, so you could avoid using spaces and double quotes:

```
set stl+=%{&spell?line('.'):''}
```

Or you can use the `:let` command:

```
let &stl .= '%{&spell ? line(".") : ""}'
```

This time, you don't need to escape anything. But to add this value to the `'statusline'` option, you have to use the `.=` operator instead of `+=`, because you're concatenating strings.

---

As your last [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/how-do-i-conditionally-add-items-to-the-statusline#comment18396_10459) says it, with these syntaxes, you lose the ability to include `'%'` items inside the expression in the curly braces.

In this case, you could consider another syntax, described in `:h 'stl`:

```
When the option starts with "%!" then it is used as an expression,
evaluated and the result is used as the option value.  Example: >
    :set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()
The result can contain %{} items that will be evaluated too.
```

So, maybe you could add something like this in your `vimrc`:

```
set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()

fu! MyStatusLine() abort
    if &spell
        " return the items when `'spell'` is enabled
        return '%P %m %l'
    else
        " return the items when `'spell'` is disabled
        return '%P %m'
    endif
endfu
```

Or shorter:

```
set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()
fu! MyStatusLine() abort
    return '%P %m ' . (&spell ? '%l ' : '')
endfu
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Honestly, I was looking for something that would allow me to use any of the statusline flags, `%P`, `%m`, or even colors like `%1*`.